# how to send the array of the checkbox values in Jquery to rout Symfony

Tags: jquery, symfony

the majority of projects are said depend using JS (I am a beginner in the use JS).

So in my project (I use technology SF 2.7), I posted my after my BD data in a table by assigning each line with a "checkbox" button and a button "CheckAll" found in header of table for selecting my data lines.

after the search on google, I got the 1st operate CheckAll that is to say, when I click on the button "CheckAll" tres all buttons will be selected.

The only problem that remains is how to retrieve and send ids (I speak of the value of the checkbox) to my path "deleteAll"
for example if I have selected two bontons so I have to have two ids for delete.

My code html:

```
<!-- menu dropdown-->

<form id="deleteAll" method="post" action="{{ path('deleteAll') }}">
    <strong>
        <i class="fa fa-trash" ></i> Delete
    </strong>
    <!-- ./menu dropdown -->

    <!-- table -->
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
                    <!-- ici le bouton checkAll-->
                </th>
                <th>
                    Project title
                </th>
                <th>
                    Date Added
                </th>
                <th>
                    Modification date
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for entity in entities %}

            <tr class="gradeC">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="d" name="check[]" value=" {{ entity.id }}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>{{ entity.ProjectTitle }}</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>{{ entity.dateAdd |date('d-m-Y') }} </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>{{  entity.dateModification| date('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}                                            </strong>
                </td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

    </table>

</form>
```

-My code JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#checkAll").click(function(){

                var checked_status = this.checked;

                $("input[name='check[]']").each(function(){

                    this.checked = checked_status;
                    var v = $("#d").val();

                    $('#deleteAll').on('submit', function (e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        actiondesubsitution();
                    });
                });

            });
        });


    </script>
```

Can you help me please? I am a beginner in jQuery.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear, is your problem sending the values of your checkboxes to your app ? Do you want to send cb1=true, cb2=false, cb3=...  ?

Comment: the problem is sending the values of checkboxes to my route "deleteAll".
So I must have cb1 = 1, cb2 = 2 according to the id of the project which is recovered after the BD.

If the user clicks the "delete" menu ids so selected will be sent to this route.

Comment: your code is poorly indented and 'broken' : </form> inside a loop. please edit your post first :)

Comment: your problem doesnt seem to be linked to JQuery, just submit your form with an input type="submit", and handle the result of the query in your php..

Comment: It works, thank you sir for your help. but you know what function I can make a second flight to alert (sweet alert: http: //lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/) to the user before deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1- we must add the submit button has form.

2- changed this code

```
$('#deleteAll').on('submit', function (e){ 
  ....
  });
```

by

```
$('#deleteAll').trigger('submit', function (e){ 
      ....
      });
```